# Intelligent textbox processing

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with 2 RichTextBoxes, a Browse for file button and a Process button. Here is a snapshot:

[image]

I got the Browse button to open file dialog & user selects a file and the path of the file is displayed in the smaller Richtextbox2. I have also kept the option for the user to manually paste the contents of the file in the bigger RichTextBox1.

What I want is:

When the "Process" button is clicked, check if user has pasted the output in the bigger RichTextBox1 (if yes then process with the data from RichtextBox1) OR the user has browsed for the file (if yes then process with the data from RichtextBox2).

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
If RichTextBox1.TextLength > 0 Then
    ' Process text pasted
ElseIf RichTextBox2.TextLength > 0 Then
    ' Process text from the file selected
Else
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR: No text to read!")
End If
```